# Variable can't be used outside SQL statement

Tags: oracle

Hey I'm building this stored procedure:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE procedure fillCompanyWH
        IS
        cursor c is select other_line_key from line_contact;
        cursor e is select max(comp_id) + 1 from Company_WH;
        r c%ROWTYPE;
        count PLS_INTEGER:=0;
        rr NUMBER(9);
        BEGIN
                open c; 
                open e;
                    fetch e into rr;
                    if(rr is null) THEN
                        rr:=1;
                    end if;
                count:= rr;
                loop    
                    count :=count + 1;              
                fetch c into r;
                exit when c%NOTFOUND;
                        insert into Company_WH (comp_id, comp_key) values (count,r.other_line_key);
                end loop;

                    close c;
                    close e;
        END;
        /
```

It keeps giving me an error about this line (count :=count + 1;  )
the error says that (Statement ignored function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a SQL statement only).

Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT is inbuilt function. Try renaming your variable.

Comment: Thanks so much I had no idea :)

Answer (score 4):

`COUNT` is a reserved word so you cannot use it for your variable identifier.  Change it to something else.